# Xamarin Forms - Android tab bar with centered icons & no text

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm looking to remove the text from the tabs (and vertically center the icon) on a TabbedPage in my Xamarin Forms app, like this:

[image: TabBar on iOS]

I achieved this on iOS by making the TextColor clear and shifting the image down in a custom renderer:

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

    if (TabBar != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
        {
            item.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(5, 0, -5, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now my tabs on Android look like this:

[image: Android Tab Bar]

If it matters, it's been set it to the bottom of the screen like so:

```
public MyTabbedPage()
{
    On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
}
```

How can I remove the text and center the icon on the Android tab bar? I've tried playing around with the styles and axml but I'm not getting anywhere at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I pieced together a solution similar to how I did iOS, using this renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer ))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var childViews = GetAllChildViews(ViewGroup);

            var scale = Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
            var paddingDp = 9;
            var dpAsPixels = (int)(paddingDp * scale + 0.5f);

            foreach (var childView in childViews)
            {                
                if (childView is BottomNavigationItemView tab)
                {                    
                    tab.SetPadding(tab.PaddingLeft, dpAsPixels, tab.PaddingRight, tab.PaddingBottom);
                }
                else if (childView is TextView textView)
                {                 
                    textView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                }
            }
        }

        List<Android.Views.View> GetAllChildViews(Android.Views.View view)
        {
            if (!(view is ViewGroup group))
            {
                return new List<Android.Views.View> { view };
            }

            var result = new List<Android.Views.View>();

            for (int i = 0; i < group.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var child = group.GetChildAt(i);

                var childList = new List<Android.Views.View> { child };
                childList.AddRange(GetAllChildViews(child));

                result.AddRange(childList);
            }

            return result.Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

This achieves the desired result (centered icon with no text). Haven't tested it on different device sizes yet, so that magic number 9dp might not work universally.

Comment: Hey man, Any chance you have your iOS solution available? This was perfect. I come from an iOS background and am still finding this challenging.

Comment: If I remember correctly it was just as in the first code block of the OP. Set the ImageInsets of each item in TabBar.Items to slightly shift the image. Also need to set the TextColor of the TabBar.Items to Clear/Transparent. Do this in the ViewWillLayoutSubviews override of the TabbedPageRenderer. I don't have the whole renderer to hand right now but I think that was all it took.

Comment: iOS was simple. 
using RedSwipe.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace RedSwipe.iOS
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

            foreach (UITabBarItem item in this.TabBar.Items)
            {
                item.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(6, 0, -6, 0);
            }
        }

    }

}

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for the iOS counterpart to @Alex West's code.

```
using RedSwipe.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace RedSwipe.iOS
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

            foreach (UITabBarItem item in this.TabBar.Items)
            {
                item.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(6, 0, -6, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be some easy way to do that from shared project itself. Here use customrenderer to get it work.
First create xaml file in Layout folder in Android project
*custom_tab_layout.xaml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Give height, margins & Color according your preference.

Now add .CS file in your android project say `MyTabbedPageRenderer`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyTabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Myproject.Droid
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        protected override void SetTabIcon(TabLayout.Tab tab, FileImageSource icon)
        {
            base.SetTabIcon(tab, icon);
            tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.custom_tab_layout);
            var imageview = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon);
            imageview.SetBackgroundDrawable(tab.Icon);
        }
    }
}
```

The first line of code `ExportRenderer(typeof(MyTabbedPage)` have file `MyTabbedPage` is your shared project class as you mentioned in your question. In custom_tab_layout.xaml file you can add TextView too & can give text as "" in custom renderer to give a better position to your icons.
Hope it help you.

Comment: Looked into it and it seems that if the tab bar is set to the bottom, then SetTabIcon is never called at all.

Comment: I wanted to test it but your code  `On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);` showing errors for me. Is there any library or any page structure what are you using for that line?

Comment: I believe it's from the newest version of Xamarin Forms (3.1). Seems that if it's set to the bottom this way then it uses an android BottomNavigationView. Looking into ways of accessing the style of the view so I can bump the icon like I did with iOS.

Comment: Can I know your class `MyTabbedPage` from which class inheriting?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage. My current forms version is 3.1.0.637273. Right now I'm looking into renderers for the BottomNavigationItemViews.

Answer (score 1):

Like wrote [Alex West](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4600892/alex-west), but fix magic padding to this

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)tab.GetChildAt(0).LayoutParameters;
lp.Height = LayoutParams.MatchParent;
lp.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
```

Also, optionally you can fix `GetAllChildView()` method like that:

```
    List<T> GetAllChildViews<T>(Android.Views.View view) where T: Android.Views.View
    {
        if (!(view is ViewGroup group))
        {
            if(view is T)
            {
                return new List<T> { view as T };
            }

            return new List<T>();
        }

        var result = new List<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < group.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var child = group.GetChildAt(i);

            var childList = new List<T>();
            if(child is T item)
            {
                childList.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                childList.AddRange(GetAllChildViews<T>(child));
            }

            result.AddRange(childList);
        }

        return result.Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

And call it like: `GetAllChildViews<BottomNavigationMenuView>(ViewGroup)`